# GCC produces unaligned function address on Cortex M3

Tags: function, gcc, cortex-m

I just placed a function to a specific address using a section and then I output the address of that function and the result is the chosen section address + 1.
This is what I did:

```
void __attribute__((section (".my_fct_address"))) Fct_Ptr_Test (void)
{
...
}
```

and

```
void (*fct_ptr) (void);
fct_ptr = Fct_Ptr_Test;
printf ("0X%X\r\n", (uint32_t)(fct_ptr));
fct_ptr ();
```

in ld-file:

```
.my_fct_address 0x800F000 :
 {
   KEEP(*(.my_fct_address)) /* keep my variable even if not referenced */
 } > FLASH
```

The above printf statement outputs 0x800F001 and Fct_Ptr_Test is called properly

If I set

```
fct_ptr = 0x800F000;
```

the system crashes.
If I set

```
fct_ptr = 0x800F001;
```

everything is fine again.
If I don't place Fct_Ptr_Test in its own section , ie let the linker place it anywhere I also get an odd address.
Now I wonder how 0x800F001 can be a proper address on a 32 bit controller (ARM cortex M3) and what is stored in 0x800F000.
Even more strange: map-file always shows the even addresses
Can anybody help?

Thanks

Martin

Comment: Totally unrelated to your question and problem, but the portable way to print a pointer using `printf` is with the `"%p"` format. It requires the argument to be a `void *`.

Answer (score 3):

Linker sets the least-significant bit of Thumb functions to 1 to facilitate interworking (see [docs](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0471e/Babfjhia.html)). Perhaps that's your case?

Comment: Hi yugr, yes I think that's it. Thanks a lot also for the link. Martin

Comment: It is definitely the case!

Comment: To say it a different way since there isnt interworking on a thumb only machine (cortex-m3), some instructions like bx and pop expect the lsbit to be set for thumb based branch or return addresses.  See the BX instruction documentation.